# How is this a High Pass filter?

Tags: filter

Might be a dumb question, but isn't this a Low Pass filter? If not can someone explain me how it is a High Pass filter?

[image]

This is the link for the complete document: http://www.circuitbasics.com/design-hi-fi-audio-amplifier-lm3886/

Comment: Mark the input and the output of the circuit, please. As far as I am concerned (looking at your current picture) it is just a voltage follower op amp circuit loaded with a series RC circuit. If the output is the voltage on Ci, then it would bee a buffered lowpass RC filter.

Comment: Add a link to the app note or data sheet that came from, please.

Comment: That schematic section is wrong (specifically the connection to the output of the amplifier). It is a section of a larger schematic in which there are other components in the feedback loop. That is only part of the feedback loop. Please add some context to the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry its here http://www.circuitbasics.com/design-hi-fi-audio-amplifier-lm3886/

Comment: It is a high-pass filter if you read the voltage differentially over Ri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, in that figure that is a voltage follower with a capacitive load with a resistor in series.

You need two impedance to create a divider, one in the feedback loop and one somewhere else. A high pass filter needs DC blocking.

The diagram should have looked like this to illustrate the high pass portion of the entire circuit (I realize that it doesn't have a DC bias, this is for illustration only) :

[image]

Comment: Of note. Though better, that diagram is wrong in the sense that there is no DC feedback to the amplifier.

Comment: So it is a low pass filter?

Comment: @EdgarBrown see the original page for the real circuit. They are only talking about one piece of the circuit and forgot to include the entire high pass feedback loop

Comment: @ laptop2d  What he is saying that you still left out a necessary resistor from the feedback loop; He is right...

Comment: @Pllsz yes, it is. Just think about it: The higher the frequency the more current will flow through Ci, the more current will flow through (Cf-Rf2)||Rf1, the more voltage will drop on (Cf-Rf2)||Rf1. The output is the input + the voltage on  (Cf-Rf2)||Rf1. -> For the same input amplitudes the output will be higher and higher as the frequency gets higher and higher: that is a high pass filter.

Comment: Oh okay, cause I did the transfer function of that section and got a Low pass characteristics I was just confused cause in the article he said high pass, so did he make a mistake or?

Comment: As @EdgarBrown points out, this schematic is vitally missing Rf1.

Comment: This circuit that @laptop2d provided is a high-pass filter. At low frequencies, the input is disconnected from the output. At sufficiently high frequencies, you have your typical non-inverting amplifier with gain of (1+Rf2)/(Ri). Thus, you have a HPF.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the circuit in the article, if we ignore the high pass filter formed by Cin and Rin, the amplifier has unity gain at DC because Ci has no effect. At a frequency sufficiently high for reactance of Ci to be much lower than Ri, the amplifier gain is approximately Rf1/Ri + 1 = 21. This is the high pass effect.

Comment: The posted schematic does not match what you describe.  If you have found errors in the schematic, you should let OP know.

Comment: @OskarSkog note that I did not refer to the circuit diagram in the original post but the full schematic in the article linked. Plenty of people have already pointed out that the circuit is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It would have been clearer if you had actually copied the circuit you linked to. The actual circuit looked like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fax5xs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where I've added the output resistance of the 386 as R2.

For low frequencies, the impedance of C1 is very high, and the gain around the follower is roughly 1 - that is, it's a good follower.

At much higher frequencies, well above the audio, the impedance of C1 becomes small, and you can then see that the gain of the 386 will become much less, so it will not support much amplification at that frequency. This prevents the circuit from oscillating at high frequencies.

If you look closely at the linked circuit, you'll notice that R1 is quite high power. So another way of considering the circuit is that at high frequencies the load impedance will be small, and the amplifier will not be able to drive much power.

This is actually quite a common technique for stabilizing power op amps.

Comment: are we looking at the same circuit? I see a feedback path, which defines the frequency response, containing Ri, Ci, Rf1, Rf2 and Cf.